# Convergence of $\sum a_n$ (quasi-Cauchy condensation test)

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $a_n\geq a_{n+1}$ for $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Is There any example of $a_n$ which satisfies $$\sum a_n<\infty \nLeftrightarrow\sum 2^na_{2^n}<\infty$$

I found an example of $a_n$ which satisfies $$\sum a_n<\infty \nLeftrightarrow\sum 2^na_{2^n}<\infty$$when decreasing condition deleted from cauchy condensation conditions, but It's hard to generate example in this case.

I think $a_n$ must have negative terms but I don't have any idea to construct $a_n$.

So, I need any hints for constructing $a_n$ which satisfies this or proving there's no $a_n$ for this.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you are using $<\infty$ for convegence (which should not be done!) then there is no such example. If $ \sum a_n$ converges then $a_n \to 0$. Since $a_n$ is decreasing it follows that $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n$. If $\sum 2^{n}a_{2^{n}}$ converges then $2^{n}a_{2^{n}} \to 0$ which implies $a_{2^{n}} \to 0$. But then $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n$.